# How to iterate between two lists and print any missing items with a for in loop

Tags: python

I had some trouble phrasing this question, and if there is a better way to phrase this question let me know and I will edit the question.

I have a premade list of files, and another list that is generated with os.walk. The code will compare each list, and if thee is any differences it will print out 'File x is missing at y'. So far, I have got it down to doing this, however if there are more than one missing file, it prints out the same statement twice, and shows each item location(y) together.

For a better example here is the code:

```
import os

required_files = [
    'datatypes.dtd'           ,
    'xml.xsd'                 ,
    'anyElement.xsd'          ,
    'dataTypes.dtd'           ,
    'extend/strict.xsd'       ,
    'unique/loose.xsd'        ,
    'unique/strict.xsd'       ,
    'vocab/custom.xsd'        ,
    'vocab/loose.xsd'         ,
    'vocab\strict.xsd'        , #my test example. This is purposefully wrong to make sure it shows up to better debug
]

def check_name(x):
    path = x
    directory = path.replace("/", "\\")

    for d in next(os.walk(directory))[1]:
            itempath = os.path.join(directory, d)
            path = d
            if any(letter.isupper() for letter in path):
                    print(" Root folder contains invalid characters at:\n" + itempath) # skeleton veriifcation to make sure course root folder contains no uppercase letters
            
            required = [] 
            check_required = [] 
            for i in required_files:
                filepath = os.path.join(directory, d, i)
                required.append(filepath)

            for root, directories, files in os.walk(directory):

                 for name in directories: 
                  # Search for directories that contain any illegal characters 
                      if any(letter.isupper() for letter in name):
                              print(f"The Folder '{name}' contains illegal characters at\n" + os.path.join(root, name))

              for name in files:
                             # Search for files that contain any illegal characters , excluding any that ends with the extensions .xsd and .dtd
                      if not name.endswith(('.xsd', '.dtd')) and  not name.islower():
                                 print(f"The File '{name}' contains illegal characters at\n" + os.path.join(root, name))
                      elif name.endswith(('.xsd', '.dtd')):
                              check_required.append(root + '\\' + name)


            if required not in check_required:
                  missing_files = set(required) - set(check_required_files)
                  missing_file = str(missing_files).replace(r'\\', '\\') #I was getting a double slash issue when printed, so I added this to only get single slash
                  print(f'File {i} is missing at \n {missing_file}')
```

The real life example I would want this to work is as such:

```
'File vocab\strict.xsd is missing at:
    C:\Users\....vocab\strict.xsd'
'File vocab\loose.xsd is missing at:
    C:\Users\....vocab\loose.xsd'
```

Instead, I get:

```
'File vocab\strict.xsd is missing at
  {C:\Users\....vocab\strict,xsd'}
```

Or with multiple errors

```
'File vocab\strict.xsd is missing at
 {C:\Users\....vocab\strict,xsd', 'C:\Users\...unique/strict'} #created a second false positive to test this one
```

I tried adding in

```
for name in missing file:
        print(f'File {i} is missing at \n {missing_file}')
```

But this caused a print issue where it would repeated print the same line over and over again. How can I get this to work as intended?

Comment: `filepath = os.path.join(directory, d, i)` is not inside the `for d` loop. So it just uses the last value of `d` from the loop. Is that what you want?

Comment: `print(f'File {i} is missing at \n {missing_file}')` is not in the `for i` loop.

Comment: `if required not in check_required_files:` There's no variable `check_required_files`. Did you mean `check_required`? `required` is a list, not a single filename. So that condition will always be true.

Comment: @Barmar sorry, that was a format mistake. I had to copy this from another machine and made some mistakes. Is this better?

Comment: Have you considered `difflib` usage (stl)? It should be possible to do it natively and thus in C and with less boilerplate.

Comment: @SUTerliakov this looks promising, but I'm not sure if I would be able to make it say x file is missing from y location as opposed to showing the location for anything that is missing?